# Add default image if carrierwave image isn't uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm adding a photo uploader and would like to add a default image if a user photo isn't uploaded ? Would like to know what's wrong with my 'if' statement.

I'm just getting out of a coding bootcamp so excuse the newbie code.  Apologize in advance for that.  The image shows in my navbar if I upload it but if I don't upload it nothing will show in my navbar.

This is my user.rb file

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def set_photo
    if self.photo.nil?
      @photos = ['monsters/1', 'monsters/2', 'monsters/3', 'monsters/4', 'monsters/5', 'monsters/6', 'monsters/7', 'monsters/8']
      self.photo = @photos.sample
      self.save!
    end
  end
```

This is my navbar

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <%= cl_image_tag current_user.photo, class: "avatar dropdown-toggle", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>
```

This is my Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
  end

  def dashboard
    @group = Group.new
    @user_group = UserGroup.new
    @user_groups = current_user.user_groups
    @groups = current_user.groups
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    current_user.available_balance += params[:user][:deposit].to_f unless params[:user][:deposit].nil?
    current_user.available_balance -= params[:user][:withdrawal].to_f unless params[:user][:withdrawal].nil?
    current_user.save!
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :photo)
  end
end
```

This is my PhotoUploader

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
end
```

I don't receive any error messages but the image uploads fine and the avatar goes into the navbar but if I dont upload an image nothing appears at all and it won't grab a default "monster" pic.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official carrierwave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url) you should provide `default_url`, like this:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

For your case it may looks so:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

After that you should create `fallback` folder under `assets/images` and put `default.png` file into it. Don't forget to restart you application.

Also, you should mount `PhotoUploader` at your `User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  ...
end
```

**UPDATE**

I never used `cloudinary` gem before, but after some search I found this [blog post](https://stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/techtips/setting-a-default-image-when-using-cloudinary-and-carrierwave-in-rails/)

> From #default_public_id you should return the public id of an already
>   uploaded image, e.g. ‘avatar’.
>
> The #default_url method lets you specify a URL to use, skipping
>   Cloudinary completely, so you could use an asset in your project.
>
> The final point to note is that when you use the image in the view you
>   must call #url on your version, else the defaults do not get used.

And example:

```
class Client::HeadshotUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

 version :circle do
   cloudinary_transformation format: :png, transformation: [
     {effect: :improve},
     {width: 300, height: 300, crop: :thumb, gravity: :face, radius: :max}
   ]
 end

 def default_public_id
   'headshot'
 end
end
```

and then in your view

```
<%= cl_image_tag client.headshot.circle.url %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I gave that a shot but it didn't work.  Do i have to do anything with my user.rb file ?

Comment: ```
  after_create :set_photo, :set_balance 

  def set_photo
    if self.photo.nil?
      @photos = ['monsters/1', 'monsters/2', 'monsters/3', 'monsters/4', 'monsters/5', 'monsters/6', 'monsters/7', 'monsters/8']
      self.photo = @photos.sample
      self.save!
    end
  end```

Comment: @Michael Did you mount uploader at your model? I've updated answer with example.

Comment: Yea I did that already as well.  Sorry about the code I tried to add it in the comment it clearly didnt come out good

Comment: @Michael Answer updated at uploader section. What exactly you see in image code in developer tools? Is it 404 path or empty? I've reject your edits,  because it's not a reason of your problem.

Comment: I looked in the dev tools and the it's just empty. <%= cl_image_tag current_user.photo, class: "avatar dropdown-toggle", id: "navbarDropdown", data: { toggle: "dropdown" }, 'aria-haspopup': true, 'aria-expanded': false %>

Comment: @Michael Updated answer with another example.

Comment: I give up man this is never going to work. I tried literally everything. Can't thank you enough for all the suggestions though

Comment: @Michael If you may share your app code on github, I can try to review it )